# How do I load a PHP page after the page has fully loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, querying

I am relatively new to working with PHP and more specifically JQuery, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to load a small html table that has php information that I have queried game servers for like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syq9x.png).

Except... this creates quite a large loading time for the page, and I was wondering if there was a way to load the html page, display a "Loading..." sort of text and then load the PHP table from a separate file.
My PHP/HTML for the table can be found
[here](http://pastebin.com/dZkbaV40).

So to sum up, If possible, I would like a page that says "Loading..." (or something of the sort) and then once the entire HTML page has been loaded, the table of servers to appear.

I hope that I have provided all relevant information and if anything more is required please ask below, as any help would be appreciated! Again, please excuse my lack of knowledge as I am relatively new to all of this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to use AJAX, can you provide us some code?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I dunno why @Bora linked to doc ready event?? Anyways check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another php file "yourTableFile.php" with, by example

```
<table>
<?php
    foreach ($toto as $tutu)
        echo "<tr><td>" . $tutu . "</td></tr>";   
?>
</table>
```

And in your first page put the script

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#mySlowTable').load("yourTableFile.php");
});
</script>
```

then, where you want to show it :

```
<div id="mySlowTable">
    Your loading image here
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, works much butter, faster page loading...

Answer (score 1):

In the main page:

```
<div id="theTable">Loading...</div>

$(function() { $("#theTable).load("url/to/table.php"); });
```